# Compiling a Font into a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, fonts

My software requires a font to be installed prior to use (or basic formatting will break the GUI of it). For desktop machine users, this poses no issues as they can install the font manually/separately, but for some users that are installing it on a server, the fact that the font needs to be installed separately effectively breaks the application, rendering it useless.

Is there any way to package the font into a .dll (given there are no licensing issues with the font itself)?